# File to dictionary alphabetical loss

Tags: python, file, dictionary, alphabetic

So, right now I have a text filed with alternating rows of state name abbreviations and their respective populations. The file is sorted alphabetically, with AK being the first line and so on. I am trying to put all of these into a dictionary, with the abbreviation being the key and the population being the value. This is my code so far.

```
for line in f1:
    key, val = line.split()
    population[key] = int(val)
    fontsize.append(int(val))
```

However, when I try to print my dictionary called population, I get

```
{'WA': 5894121, 'DE': 783600, 'DC': 572059, 'WI': 5363675, 'WV': 1808344, 'HI': 1211537, 'FL': 15982378, etc.}
```

Is there a reason why it is it alphabetical anymore?

Answer (score 3):

Python `dict`s do not preserve order. You want to use an `OrderedDict` from the `collections` module. `OrderedDict`s preserve key order in the order they were added.

The order of `dict` keys is consistent but not necessarily anything useful.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict